# Border not showing on select cells in table

Tags: css, border

Select cells are not displaying borders in my table. There doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason; there are just a few cells that don't display the borders properly, even though the surrounding cells render just fine. I've tried to isolate the problem, but without luck.

Please excuse the inline CSS - I don't have stylesheet access in the CMS, requiring everything to be inline. Not sure if it's relevant, but everything worked when I planned this out with a stylesheet before switching to inline CSS.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

```html
<!---4/5:COMMUNITY ENGAGEMENT TABLE--->
<table style="width:90%;font-family:Tahoma;font-size: 11px;color:#253E6E;text-align:center;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0px;">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="dbblue" style="text-align:left; background-color:#253E6E;  font-family: Tahoma;color: white; font-size:13px;">
      <td colspan="5" style="padding-left:5px;">COMMUNITY ENGAGEMENT</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="dbred" style="text-align:center; background-color:#A33D4A; font-family: Tahoma; color: white; font-size:11px;">
        <td class="row1" style="width:10%;border-width:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:#253E6E; padding:3px;">Initial Baseline</td>
        <td class="row2" style="width:25%;border-width:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:#253E6E; padding:3px;">Indicator / Metric</td>
        <td class="row3" style="width:10%;border-width:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:#253E6E; padding:3px;">2016-17 Status</td>
        <td class="row4" style="width:45%;border-width:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:#253E6E; padding:3px;">Rationale / Details</td>
        <td class="row5" style="width:10%;border-width:1px; border-style:solid; border-color:#253E6E; padding:3px;">2018 Goal</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#253E6E;padding:3px;">Began Formal Process in 2013-14</td>
        <td style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#253E6E;padding:3px;">Maintain Effective Community Engagement</td>
        <td class="dbgreen">Process on Schedule -<br /><a href="/cms/lib/IL01001538/Centricity/Domain/2005/Community Engagement Planning.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Work Plan</a></td>
        <td style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#253E6E;padding:3px;">During the Engage 200 process, our community requested the Board remain connected to the community to determine its priorities, foster partnerships and promote learning.</td>
        <td style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#253E6E;padding:3px;">Plan Monitored Annually</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The only cell I can see with no borders is the cell with no inline `border` properties set (`.dbgreen`).

Comment: You have not added border to 3rd td of 3rd tr

Comment: Thank you for catching that. That works perfectly.

Comment: There is an issue with the blue tr (.dbblue) - it does not span the full width of the table; it looks like it's off by a couple of px. When I used an external stylesheet, this was not an issue. I'm not sure what would cause this as the width is fixed at 90% throughout. Thank you for any help you can provide here.

Comment: Add a border to the nested `td` element of `.dbblue` as well.

Comment: By the way, do you need to write all the subproperties out in full? `border:1px solid` would be much shorter. Note that you don't need to specify the color if it's the same as the text color.

Comment: I'm not sure I would have identified that border issue, thank you. I cleaned up the old subproperties as well; thanks for the suggestion.